# Обработка POST в django

Tags: python, django

При отправке запроса получаю 403-ю? Почему?

```
def index(request):
    if 'q' in request.POST:
        q = request.POST['q']
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'q': q} )
    else:
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'q': 'error'} )
```

вот вид если что:

```
{{ q }}
<form action="" method="POST" />
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

подскажите...

Answer (score 3):

В форме добавьте `{% csrf_token %}`

Answer (score 2):

Ну для начала посмотри что говорит django и вероятнее всего он тебе говорит:

> csrf verification failed

Answer (score 1):

Читайте про CSRF

Answer (score 0):

Если CSRF для вас не имеет значение удалите из настроек (кортеж MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES) строку  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'.